# Rewrite URL using GET params

Tags: magento2, htaccess

I have a URL that looks like this:

> site.local/wheel-tyres/tyres.html?find=aprilia-af-1-futura-1989-4729&sid=T80yDaUX1a

I'm trying to get it to look like this:

> site.local/wheel-tyres/tyres/aprilia-af-1-futura-1989-4729/

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33058452/enable-human-readable-urls-in-htaccess) on StackOverflow and tried to implement with amendments I though would work, but the page 500s now.

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^*.html/(.*)$ /*.html?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This code was added to the `pub/.htaccess` file.

How do I go about getting the find param into a readable url?

Comment: Did you make all needed setup related to seo url in admin panel?

Comment: @KirillKorushkin not sure I understand - could you please try to clarify? :)

Comment: are you suing nginx or apache?

Comment: @PhilippSander Apache :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, Magento2 has 4 routers **Base > CMS > URL Rewrite > Default**
In your case, you should create a custom router.
I can suggest you create a custom module and then create a custom router to solve your issue. You can do as the following steps:

> 1. Create app/code/Vendor/Module/registration.php

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_Module',
    __DIR__
);
```

> 2. Create app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="0.0.1">
    </module>
</config>
```

> 3. Create app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
  <type name="Magento\Framework\App\RouterList">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="routerList" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="custom_router" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="class" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Controller\Router</item>
                <item name="disable" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">70</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
</config>
```

> 4. Create app/code/Vendor/Module/Controller/Router.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Controller;


class Router implements \Magento\Framework\App\RouterInterface
{
    private $actionFactory;

    /**
     * Router constructor.
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\ActionFactory $actionFactory
     */

    public function __construct(\Magento\Framework\App\ActionFactory $actionFactory)
    {
        $this->actionFactory = $actionFactory;
    }

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
     * @return \Magento\Framework\App\ActionInterface|null
     */
    public function match(\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request)
    {
        $pathInfo = $request->getPathInfo();
        $find = $request->getParam('find', false);
        if ($find && preg_match("%^/.*/.*\.html$%", $pathInfo, $m)) {
            $pathInfo = str_replace('.html', '', $pathInfo);
            $pathInfo = $pathInfo . '/' . $find . '/';
            $request->setPathInfo($pathInfo);
            return $this->actionFactory->create('Magento\Framework\App\Action\Forward',
                ['request' => $request]);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

5. Install new module by this command:

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade

This module will support to convert the url like

> site.local/wheel-tyres/tyres.html?find=aprilia-af-1-futura-1989-4729/

to

> site.local/wheel-tyres/tyres/aprilia-af-1-futura-1989-4729/

Hope this will solve your issue

Cheers

Comment: wait - should be the other way round: `site.local/wheel-tyres/tyres.html?find=aprilia-af-1-futura-1989-4729/` to `site.local/wheel-tyres/tyres/aprilia-af-1-futura-1989-4729/`

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I've updated my answer. Please check it. Thanks

Comment: I have up-voted your answer, It seems correct

Answer (score -1):

Configure URL Rewrites in Magento 2

- On the Admin Panel, Stores > Settings > Configurations.
- In the left panel, under General, select Web.
- Open the Search Engine Optimization section.
- Select "YES"
- Clear configuration cache

[source](https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-configure-url-rewrite-magento-2.html)

Comment: it's already set to YES